# Getting list of sent push notifications from APNS server (iOS)

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is there any way to get list of sent push notifications from APNS server for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, There isn't anyway in which you can get list of notifications which APN server has already sent you.

Though, a work around can help you. You can keep logs of all the notifications sent to each and every particular device (which is usually there at server) and to get the records you can have a GET api call. To make it efficient you can maintain a timestamp on server, which will indicate till which time you have already requested for notifications.For Example :

1. Initially timestamp = 0
2. Let's assume that a 12 notifications are received between timestamp = 0 to timestamp = 23
3. Now you make GET api call for notifications, you will receive all the notifications and server will update timestamp corresponding to your device token as 23.
4. Again between timestamp = 23 and timestamp = 89, 2 notifications are received.
5. You make Get api call request can you will receive only the two  new notifications and server will again update its timestamp for your device token.

**Note :**

1. Timestamps are just virtual and used for illustration purpose.
2. The optimisation suggested may/may-not be according to your need.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the list form the APNS sever, because I am not receiving any push notifications at all.

Comment: then rather than trying to fetch list of push notifications from APNs server you need to debug why aren't you getting push notifications.